terraform assertion raises only warning
I am using terraform check block to check whether the environment provided by user matches the selected workspace. When I do apply or plan, I do see that assertion check has failed (for mismatched values) but it doesn't throw an error. Is there a way to raise an error when the assertion check fails. My idea is to halt plan or apply operation if the provided environment doesn't match the selected workspace before proceeding to apply/check for other resources.
variable "env" {
  type = string
  validation {
    condition     = contains(["dev", "staging", "pre-prod", "prod"], var.env)
    error_message = "env must be one of dev | staging | pre-prod | prod"
  }
}

check "validate_env" {
  assert {
    condition     = var.env == terraform.workspace
    error_message = "environment and terraform workspace do not match"
  }
}

This produces following warning message:
❯ terraform apply
var.env
  Enter a value: prod


No changes. Your infrastructure matches the configuration.

Terraform has compared your real infrastructure against your configuration and found no
differences, so no changes are needed.
╷
│ Warning: Check block assertion failed
│
│   on main.tf line 20, in check "validate_env":
│   20:     condition     = var.env == terraform.workspace
│     ├────────────────
│     │ terraform.workspace is "dev"
│     │ var.env is "prod"
│
│ environment and terraform workspace do not match
╵

Apply complete! Resources: 0 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.


From Assertions:

Unlike other custom conditions, assertions do not affect Terraform's execution of an operation. A failed assertion reports a warning without halting the ongoing operation. This contrasts with other custom conditions, such as a postcondition, where Terraform produces an error immediately, halting the operation and blocking the application or planning of future resources.

